# Show vhistory in list of tables or ignore it in table numbering

Tags: tables, numbering

I'm using the package *vhistory*:

```
\begin{versionhistory}
        \vhEntry{0.1}{01.01.1970}{JD}{Created}
\end{versionhistory
```

In the document (document class article) I have another table:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
            Example & Example & Example \\
    \end{tabular}
        \caption{Example}
\end{table
```

At the end of the document I have a list of tables:

```
\listoftables
```

My problem now is that in the caption of the table it says *Table 2: Example* and in the List of Figures it says *2 Example .......... 2*. The numbering for the table starts with 2 because of the vhistory.

I want that the table numbering starts with 1 for the example table or that the vhistory is shown in the list of tables. I want that to avoid any confusion about missing tables.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that your version history table is the first table in your document, after your versionhistory environment add:

```
\setcounter{table}{0}
```

This will reset the table numbering, so that the next table will get number 1.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work for links, though :/